# Visual Studio Team Services Release Definition - Task to rename a file?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

How can I rename a file in a release definition in Visual Studio Team services? Is there a built-in or marketplace task available or otherwise, how can this be achieved?

**Answer:**

1. Add the "Inline PowerShell" task from the marketplace
2. Enter the following PowerShell code in the text area

   ```
   Param
   (
    [string]$pathToFileToRename
   )

   Rename-Item $pathToFileToRename NewName.txt
   ```
3. Enter any required arguments in the arguments text box (you can use environment variables), for example.

   ```
   pathToFileToRename $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somepath/CurrentName.txt
   ```

Comment: I think part 3 of the answer should have the parameter names prefixed with a hyphen. So it should be `-pathToFileToRename $(...` etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Run Command Line task or do it in a PowerShell script and invoke the script in your release.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the actual fixed based on your suggestion