# Using TFS Release Management, I need a task to rename a file

Tags: tfs, continuous-deployment

I'm using TFS Release Management.  In my deployment, I want to replace tokens in a file, but first, I need a task to rename the file (overwriting the one that is there already).

Seems like it should be super obvious, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplicate with this question: [Visual Studio Team Services Release Definition - Task to rename a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357662/visual-studio-team-services-release-definition-task-to-rename-a-file)

Try this method:

> 1) Add the "Inline Powershell" task from the **marketplace**
>
> 2) Enter
>   the following Powershell in the text area
>
> ```
> Param  
> (  
>  [string]$pathToFileToRename  
> )  
>
> Rename-Item $pathToFileToRename NewName.txt
> ```
>
> 3) Enter any required arguments in the arguments text box (you can
>   use environment variables) e.g.
>
> ```
> pathToFileToRename $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somepath/CurrentName.txt
> ```

How to run the task please refer this blog: [Using the Inline PowerShell VSTS task](https://pgroene.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/using-the-inline-powershell-vsts-task/)